# a double-quoted delimited-identifier error SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

**Hi everyone am experiencing this error in oracle**

```
Errors: TRIGGER NOUPDATE
Line/Col: 9/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

**This is the code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NoUpdate
  BEFORE UPDATE OF apartmentsize ON rental
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  apartmentsize INT(22);
BEGIN
  IF (apartmentsize < 60) THEN
    BEGIN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20112,
                              'You cannot update the apartmentsize');
      ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: @Abra i did try to remove it and it will just work but it wont fire the trigger it will just update without triggering "you cannot update apartmentsize"

Comment: `apartmentsize int(22)` is declared but never assigned, therefore `(apartmentsize<60)` is never true

Comment: If you're trying to raise an exception if the table has fewer than 60 rows, then you're asking for trouble. You're likely to encounter ORA-4091 when you count the rows in the table that's changing.

Comment: Nothing but an `END;` is missing just after `ROLLBACK;`. Alternatively, you can prefer  removing `BEGIN` just after the line of `IF..THEN`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thank you so much it worked

Comment: @AterLux your logic helped bro and i finally managed to debug my code thanks.

Comment: @jayCoder Just adding `END` will make the trigger compile but it will not make the trigger work as the variable `apartmentsize` is declared locally and will have a `NULL` value; it does not take the value of the updated row as it is just a local variable. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=540c775b0789b011b220277f19eb754a)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's firing the trigger but the IF condition is never true.  I don't see anywhere that you assign a value to apartmentsize.

If you think it is this statement:

```
apartmentsize int(22);
```

Then no, that is simply saying that aparmentsize is declared as a 22-digit integer.  If you want to assign a value:

```
apartmentsize int := 22;
```

And according to the 18c SQL Language Reference, 'int' is not a valid data type.  Supported numeric data types are:
number
float
binary_float
binary_double

What you want is NUMBER(precision,scale).  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlqr/Data-Types.html#GUID-219C338B-FE60-422A-B196-2F0A01CAD9A4).

Comment: well i didnt want to assign a value to apartmentsize because the column apartmentsize already have some values so i just want to stop the user from trying to update the apartmentsize to a size which is less than 60.I know i declared apartmentsize because it was complaining that apartmentsize needs to be declared if i want to use it in the if statement

Comment: i did  add this apartmentsize int := 22; and it worked thank you so much and i did combine with another commentor's code

Comment: @EdStevens INT is  a valid supported data type. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF).  It seems that Oracle has separated the data type they define and the data types ANSI defined. But they support all ANSI data types. In sys.standard INT is effectively defined NUMBER(38,0).

Comment: @Belayer - ah, I was looking further up in the same doc - under 'number data types'.  I thought there might be some acceptance of INT with internal translation, else the OP would have gotten an error just _creating_ his procedure.   Probably a bit of preference/philosophy, but it seems to me that if oracle is going to make an internal translation, one could consider just defining it as oracle will anyway.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `BEGIN` without an `END` and you probably want to use `:NEW.apartmentsize` bind variable to reference the updated value rather than declaring a variable in the trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NoUpdate
  BEFORE UPDATE OF apartmentsize ON rental
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.apartmentsize < 60) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20112,
      'You cannot update the apartmentsize'
    );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*(Note: Including `ROLLBACK` is pointless as raising the exception will implicitly trigger a rollback and once you have raised the exception the rest of the code in the trigger will not be parsed as an exception has been raised.)*

Then if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE rental ( id, apartmentsize ) AS
SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
UPDATE rental
SET    apartmentsize = 60
WHERE  id = 1;
```

Will work but:

```sql
UPDATE rental
SET    apartmentsize = 59
WHERE  id = 1;
```

Will raise the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20112: You cannot update the apartmentsize
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_DAVWBSJBRDBITOSDOROT.NOUPDATE", line 4
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_DAVWBSJBRDBITOSDOROT.NOUPDATE'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4390d4e14e0d51f10fd70ed53ee2254)*

Comment: it worked i just ran it now the only difference from what i had was that i had no referencing which is very important thank you so much